# $ABCD$ a tetrahedron. $P$ and $Q$ be points on the sides $AB$ and $CD$ respectively. What is the locus of the midpoint of the line segment $PQ$?

Tags: vectors, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Let $ABCD$ a tetrahedron. $P$ and $Q$ be points on the sides $AB$ and $CD$ respectively. What is the locus of the midpoint of the line segment $PQ$?

The locus is the set of points $X$ satisfying the condition that $X$ is the midpoint of the line segment $PQ$. How do I go about finding and describing this set?

Answer (score 1):

Say we fix $Q$ for a moment and move only $P$ on $AB$. Then $X$ describes a middle segment in $ABQ$. This segment is of lenght $AB/2$ no matter where is $Q$ on $CD$.

[image]

Let $K,L,M,N$ be a midpoints of $AC,BC,AD,BD$ respectively.

If $Q= C$ then this middle segment is $KL$ and if $Q=D$ then it is $NM$.

If $Q$ is in interior of $CD$ this middle segment has end points on segments $KN$ and $LN$.

So $X$ describes paralelogram (with it interior) $KLMN$.

Answer (score 0):

Denote points of tetrahedron with $A(0, 0, 0)$, $B(a, 0, 0)$, $C(\frac{a}2,\frac{a\sqrt 3}{2}, 0)$, $D(\frac{a}2,\frac{a\sqrt3}{6},\frac{a\sqrt6}3)$

Arbitrary points $P\in AB$ and $Q\in CD$ have the following coordinates:

$$P(pa,0,0), Q(\frac{a}2, \frac{a\sqrt3}{6}(3-2q),\frac{aq\sqrt6}3)$$

...with:

$$p,q\in[0,1]$$

Coordinates of the midpoint are:

$$M(\frac{a}4(2p+1), \frac{a\sqrt3}{12}(3-2q),\frac{aq\sqrt6}6)$$

or:

$$x=\frac{a}4(2p+1)\tag{1}$$

$$y=\frac{a\sqrt3}{12}(3-2q),\space z=\frac{aq\sqrt6}6\tag{2}$$

Obviously, you can pick the value for $x$ independently of $y,z$.

The range for $x$ is:

$$x_{p=0}=\frac{a}4,\space x_{p=1}=\frac{3a}4,$$

For any given $x$ the locus of points is given with (2) which is actually a straight line going from:

$$y_{q=0}=a\frac{\sqrt{3}}4, \space z_{q=0}=0$$

...to:

$$y_{q=1}=a\frac{\sqrt{3}}{12}, \space z_{q=1}=a\frac{\sqrt 6}6$$

So the locus of midpoints is actually a rectangle with the following coordinates:

$$(\frac{a}4, a\frac{\sqrt{3}}4, 0),\space(\frac{a}4, a\frac{\sqrt{3}}{12}, a\frac{\sqrt 6}6)$$

$$(\frac{3a}4, a\frac{\sqrt{3}}4, 0),\space(\frac{3a}4, a\frac{\sqrt{3}}{12}, a\frac{\sqrt 6}6)$$

Comment: How you find this coordinates? $$A(0, 0, 0), B(a, 0, 0), C(\frac{a}2,\frac{a\sqrt 3}{2}, 0), D(\frac{a}2,\frac{a\sqrt3}{6},\frac{a\sqrt6}3)$$ I don't think it is true in general.

Comment: Yes, it is. Calculate distances between any two points and you will find out that the distance between them is exactly $a$. Four different points with all distances between them equal to $a$ define a tetrahedron.

Comment: So you are assuming that tetrahedron has all sides equal. That is very special tetrahedron in my country.